# How to add value of one key of an array to another key of a same array?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have an array and I want to add value of one key of that array to another key of same array. This is my code

```
$current_user = $current_user->user_name;     
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $current_user;
```

Now I want to use this $_SESSION['user_name'] and add this value to another key of same array $_SESSION['_PREFERENCES']. This key has values in it. I want something like this

```
$_SESSION['(value of user_name key)_PREFERENCES']
```

Please guide me how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: If it's not `$_SESSION[$_SESSION['user_name'] . '_PREFERENCES']` then I don't know what this question is asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add concatenation:

```
$_SESSION[$_SESSION['user_name'] . '_PREFERENCES'] = $USER_PREFERENCES;
// May this variable be array or string.
```